# javascript regex validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My  java-script regex validation requires the following condition.

1. Accept only alphabet value
2. Do not accept  only numeric  value
3. Do not accept only special characters
4. Accept combination of alphanumeric and special character value

I wrote following code to achieve it

```
 function validateAlphaNumChar(str) {

        var filter = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@@./#&+-]*$/;
        if (filter.test(str)) {

            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

and I also tried different regex but never achieved the desired result.

Please do help me with the proper regex for my validations.

Thank You

Comment: https://regex101.com/ try this website to work with your regex it really helps

Comment: **To all would-be answerers** - can we not "just provide the code"? At least try and help the OP to get there themselves.

Comment: use a function instead, as you have 3 contradiction conditions

Answer (score 0):

Since, It is necessary to have alphabets in your string, simply check for that

```
function validateAlphaNumChar(str) {

        var filter = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@@./#&+-]*$/;
        var filterAlphabets = /^[ A-Za-z]*$/;
        if (filter.test(str)) {
           if ( filterAlphabets.test(str)){
            return true;
          }
          else{
          return false; }

        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is assuming that a combination of numbers and special characters is not allowed

Comment: tried but still some of the conditions not working  eg. A@    this returns false

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question right it should be like this

1. Check if it contains only numbers
2. Check if it contains only special symbols

```js
function validateAlphaNumChar(str) {
        var filterABC = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;
        var filterNUM = /^[0-9]*$/;
        var filterSPEC = /^[_@@./#&+-]*$/;
        if (filterNUM.test(str)) {
            return false;
        } else if(filterSPEC.test(str)) {
            return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = validateAlphaNumChar("A@");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```